# File is getting overridden. So, its writing content to same file every time AJAX JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, loops, logging

My code works without any errors, however its only saving the first file in the array every time. My ajax request is sending correctly to the server side however something is looping the server side multiple files function. I have 5 text files: A.txt, B.txt, C.txt, D.txt and E.txt. When i try upload all 5 files, only A.txt saves to my temp folder, but in the logs it shows the below:

```
    2017-04-13 21:29:55.876 DEBUG o.s.w.m.c.CommonsMultipartResolver.259 - Found multipart file [files[]] of size 0 bytes with original filename [A.txt], stored in memory 
2017-04-13 21:29:55.876 DEBUG o.s.w.m.c.CommonsMultipartResolver.259 - Found multipart file [files[]] of size 0 bytes with original filename [B.txt], stored in memory 
2017-04-13 21:29:55.876 DEBUG o.s.w.m.c.CommonsMultipartResolver.259 - Found multipart file [files[]] of size 0 bytes with original filename [C.txt], stored in memory 
2017-04-13 21:29:55.876 DEBUG o.s.w.m.c.CommonsMultipartResolver.259 - Found multipart file [files[]] of size 0 bytes with original filename [D.txt], stored in memory 
2017-04-13 21:29:55.876 DEBUG o.s.w.m.c.CommonsMultipartResolver.259 - Found multipart file [files[]] of size 0 bytes with original filename [E.txt], stored in memory




        Line 133078: 2017-04-13 21:29:55.831 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.402 - You have successfully uploaded 'A.txt' 
Line 133085: 2017-04-13 21:29:55.836 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.402 - You have successfully uploaded 'A.txt' 
Line 133109: 2017-04-13 21:29:55.841 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.402 - You have successfully uploaded 'A.txt' 
Line 133141: 2017-04-13 21:29:55.861 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.402 - You have successfully uploaded 'A.txt' 
Line 133189: 2017-04-13 21:29:55.884 INFO  c.g.o.i.controller.AjaxController.402 - You have successfully uploaded 'A.txt'
```

Ajax query:

```
function makeProgress(number){   
      var url = getRelativeURL("web/fileUpload");        
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('number', number);
      fls = document.getElementById("attachmentFileUploadInput").files; //number of files... 
      console.log(fls);
      for(j=0;j<fls.length;j++){
          formData.append('files[]', fls[j]);  //note files[] not files
          $.ajax({
              url : url,
              data : formData,
              processData : false,
              contentType: false,
              type : 'POST',
              success : function(data) {
               FileUploadVisible(true);
               $('#attachmentModal').modal('hide')
               $(':input','#attachmentModal').val("");
                $("#pbarmain").hide();
                $("#pbar").hide();
                $("#actionPlanDiv").hide();
                setObjectEnabled('#Upload',false);
              },
              error : function(err) {
                  FileUploadErrorVisible(true);
              }
         });
          console.log('loop each file working');
      }
      console.log("form data " + formData);


        }
```

Server side control - an issue here somehwere?

```
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C://temp//";

@RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{       

    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
    try {
        File directory = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number);
                if (! directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdir();
                  }
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number + "//" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            logger.info("You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
            return("File Uploaded");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        logger.error("Failed to upload file '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'", e);
        return("File Not Uploaded");
    }
}
    return "redirect:/fileUpload";
}

}
```

Comment: Anyone advise on the above?